# How to send the notification mail to user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I am using this link http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html to send the mail notifications to user upon the creation,deletion and edition of the user and will get the mail.It works fine for me.

Now What i want is when the user is created at the time of the creation we will have the radio button for enabling the mail notification if it is enabled then only it will get the notification mail.So what i need to do????

Any help would be appreciated..

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the UserController code only send an e-mail if the user attribute to opt into email is set:

```
    if @user.save
      # Tell the UserMailer to send a welcome Email after save 
      # IF MAIL NOTIFICATIONS ARE ENABLED
      if @user.enable_mail_notification then
         UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver
      end
    end
```

Comment: No, you would have to add this attribute to user model and update that value from the radio button you are describing

Comment: okk thanks..I have one more question related to this what i need to do if i want to send the email notification immediate or digest???

Comment: I have made an attribute named Notification and make two radio buttons but when i write the above code in the user's controller it will give an error that No Method Error enable_mail_notification in UsersController...what do i do???

Comment: enable_mail_notification was an example. Since you named your attribute Notification, you should check for user.Notification, not for user.enable_mail_notification

Comment: yes i have created the attribute named Notification it gives an error  No Method Error notification in UsersController....

Comment: dude, if you defined attribute on the User model, why are you trying to call Notification on UsersController?